# Sum $\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n+1}{k}+\binom{n+2}{k}+...+\binom{n+m}{k}$

Tags: combinatorics, sequences-and-series

Evaluate the following series sum which n, m, k are nonnegative integers.
$$\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n+1}{k}+\binom{n+2}{k}+...+\binom{n+m}{k}$$

I have no idea about it@@

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the kind of thing you are looking for, but here goes : Consider
$$
(1+x)^n + (1+x)^{n+1} + \ldots + (1+x)^{n+m} 
$$
The expression you want to evaluate is the coefficient of $x^k$ of this polynomial. So re-write it as
$$
(1+x)^n\{1 + (1+x) + \ldots + (1+x)^m\} = (1+x)^n \left \lbrace \frac{1-(1+x)^{m+1}}{1-(1+x)} \right\rbrace = \frac{(1+x)^n}{x}\left((1+x)^{m+1} - 1\right )
$$
Now expand both sides out using the Binomial theorem, and, keeping in mind the $1/x$ factor there, the coefficient of $x^k$ turns out to be
$$
\sum_{i+j=k} {n\choose i+1}{m+1\choose j}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Although you used the [generating-functions](/questions/tagged/generating-functions) tag, this problem has a nice combinatorial solution for which I’m providing an extended hint.

HINT: Let $N=\{0,1,\ldots,n+m\}$. You want to choose $k+1$ elements of $N$ in such a way that the largest element chosen is at least $n$; in how many ways can you do this?

Let $\ell$ be the largest element chosen; of course $n\le\ell\le n+m$. The other $k$ chosen numbers must come from the set $\{0,1,\ldots,\ell-1\}$, which has $\ell$ members, so there are $\binom{\ell}k$ ways to choose them. Thus, $N$ has $\binom{\ell}k$ $(k+1)$-element subsets whose largest element is $\ell$.

- Relate this to your expression.
- How many $(k+1)$-element subsets does $N$ have altogether?
- How many of those subsets have largest element less than $n$? (Further HINT: those unwanted subsets are the $(k+1)$-element subsets of ... what?)